# creating spring boot project without maven

Tags: spring, maven

I am working recently with spring boot framework
my problem is that I need to set up to environment in a device that has no internet
I have searched A lot but all I found is using maven that will handle the processes of downloading all the dependencies
put I need to add the required dependencies like the old  way when you download the jar files and add them to the class-path
is there a way to  do so with STS
or is there a way to change where the maven download the dependencies to be from local instead of internet

Comment: I would assume the device without internet is the one on which your application should run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used STS but I assume it uses maven/gradle under the hood.

You can set up local repository and point maven/gradle to it. For example you could use Nexus:
https://www.sonatype.com/products/repository-oss

Another way is to pull dependencies (they get downloaded when you do maven or gradle build and are saved under ~/.m2 or ~/.gradle directories), then copy your ~/.gradle or ~/.m2 directory to the PC with no internet and build offline. With gradle it looks like this.

```
./gradlew build --offline
```